# Check if belongsToMany relation exists - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Two of my tables (clients and products) have a ManyToMany relation using Laravel's blongToMany and a pivot table.
Now I want to check if a certain client has a certain product.

I could create a model to check in the pivot table but since Laravel does not require this model for the belongsToMany method I was wondering if there is another way to check if a certain relationship exists without having a model for the pivot table.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

I think the official way to do this is to do:

```
$client = Client::find(1);
$exists = $client->products->contains($product_id);
```

It's somewhat wasteful in that it'll do the `SELECT` query, get all results into a `Collection` and then finally do a `foreach` over the `Collection` to find a model with the ID you pass in. However, it doesn't require modelling the pivot table.

If you don't like the wastefulness of that, you could do it yourself in SQL/Query Builder, which also wouldn't require modelling the table (nor would it require getting the `Client` model if you don't already have it for other purposes:

```
$exists = DB::table('client_product')
    ->whereClientId($client_id)
    ->whereProductId($product_id)
    ->count() > 0;
```

Comment: +1. This is the official way and should be marked as best answer.

Comment: @DavidMIRV are you getting that error from the upper code sample? If so, are you sure you're calling the relationship as an attribute? If you do it as a method call (i.e. `$exists = $client->products()->contains($product_id);`) then it will indeed say that `contains` does not exist on `BelongsToMany`. However, if you call it as an attribute, the BelongsToMany is silently converted to a Collection, which *does* have `contains()`.

Comment: yeah I fixed it I can't remember exactly what the problem was but I think I was missing ::with

Comment: @GustavoStraube this method works, but it will load a lot of data into the memory just to check relationship existence.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yea, I agree with you. In my case, though, I'm already loading the related models anyway. So no extra data is loaded. Thanks for the insight, anyway. It'll probably help other people reaching this answer.

Comment: I've modeled my tables and the first approach works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Warning: this will hydrate all models retrieved in the query, taking more memory than a raw query made with the DB library directly. It might be an issue if you have a lot of models.

Comment: What's wrong with `$client->products()->whereProductId($product_id)->exists()` or similar? Then you can keep the relation definition in one place, and still benefit from filtering in the DB. Better still, create a scope e.g. `scopeForProduct` and define that only in one place too.

Answer (score 52):

The question is quite old but this may help others looking for a solution:

```
$client = Client::find(1);
$exists = $client->products()->where('products.id', $productId)->exists();
```

No "wastefulness" as in @alexrussell's solution and the query is more efficient, too.

Comment: I get error ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:``` when I try that in my model :/

Comment: @George Then try `where('products.id', $productId)`.

Comment: dont think you need table alias there, id is enought. this is determined in the products relationship. Cleanest solution sofar imho.

Comment: @Johan You need the alias if e.g. `client` has an ID too. That's quite common.

Comment: This solutions works more stable. I had problem when was iterating too fast with $client->products->contains($product_id);

Comment: Works perfectly. You can even add this to a model accessor.

Answer (score 20):

Alex's solution is working one, but it will load a `Client` model and all related `Product` models from DB into memory and only after that, it will check if the relationship exists.

A better Eloquent way to do that is to use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method.

**1.** You don't need to load client model, you can just use his ID.

**2.** You also don't need to load all products related to that client into memory, like Alex does.

**3.** One SQL query to DB.

```
$doesClientHaveProduct = Product::where('id', $productId)
    ->whereHas('clients', function($q) use($clientId) {
        $q->where('id', $clientId);
    })
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** I did not take into account the usefulness of checking multiple relations, if that is the case then @deczo has a way better answer to this question. Running only one query to check for all relations is the desired solution.

```
    /**
     * Determine if a Client has a specific Product
     * @param $clientId
     * @param $productId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function clientHasProduct($clientId, $productId)
    {
        return ! is_null(
            DB::table('client_product')
              ->where('client_id', $clientId)
              ->where('product_id', $productId)
              ->first()
        );
    }
```

You could put this in you User/Client model or you could have it in a ClientRepository and use that wherever you need it.

```
if ($this->clientRepository->clientHasProduct($clientId, $productId)
{
    return 'Awesome';
}
```

But if you already have defined the belongsToMany relationship on a Client Eloquent model, you could do this, inside your Client model, instead:

```
    return ! is_null(
        $this->products()
             ->where('product_id', $productId)
             ->first()
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

@nielsiano's methods will work, but they will query DB for every user/product pair, which is a waste in my opinion.

If you don't want to load all the related models' data, then this is what I would do for a **single user**:

```
// User model
protected $productIds = null;

public function getProductsIdsAttribute()
{
    if (is_null($this->productsIds) $this->loadProductsIds();

    return $this->productsIds;
}

public function loadProductsIds()
{
    $this->productsIds = DB::table($this->products()->getTable())
          ->where($this->products()->getForeignKey(), $this->getKey())
          ->lists($this->products()->getOtherKey());

    return $this;
}

public function hasProduct($id)
{
    return in_array($id, $this->productsIds);
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->hasProduct($someId); // true / false

// or
Auth::user()->hasProduct($someId);
```

Only 1 query is executed, then you work with the array.

---

The easiest way would be using `contains` like @alexrussell suggested.

I think this is a matter of preference, so unless your app is quite big and requires a lot of optimization, you can choose what you find easier to work with.

Comment: Great answer @deczo and amazing use of Laravel built-in helpers to make the querying dynamic in regard to keys/tables - I tend to strive for this myself but this takes it to a new level! :D

Comment: Thanks, still one must play a lot with Eloquent in order to learn which of those methods return just a key `col_id` and which qualified/prefixed `table.col_id`. Unfortunately Eloquent lacks consistency pretty often.

Comment: Yeah - I must say, with as much respect to Taylor as possible, the more you delve into Laravel the more you find irritating inconsistencies and code that isn't overly clear (and without usable comments/documentation). But hey, it's not like I could do any better!

Answer (score 7):

Hello all) My solution for this problem: i created a own class, extended from Eloquent, and extend all my models from it. In this class i written this simple function:

```
function have($relation_name, $id) {
    return (bool) $this->$relation_name()->where('id','=',$id)->count();
}
```

For make a check existing relation you must write something like:

```
if ($user->have('subscribes', 15)) {
    // do some things
}
```

This way generates only a **SELECT count(...)** query without receiving real data from tables.

Answer (score 6):

To check the existence of a relationship between 2 models, all we need is a single query against the pivot table without any joins.

You can achieve it using the built-in `newPivotStatementForId` method:

```
$exists = $client->products()->newPivotStatementForId($product->id)->exists();
```

Comment: Note that if the models use SoftDeletes, this method does not take it into account. i.e.: in this case if the product is sofdeleted, this will still be true.

Comment: Instead of using the `$product->id` property, How to detect if there's at least one record? In my case, I want to get all the clients that have at least one product, since I previously don't know the `$product->id`

Answer (score 4):

use trait:

```
trait hasPivotTrait
{
    public function hasPivot($relation, $model)
    {
        return (bool) $this->{$relation}()->wherePivot($model->getForeignKey(), $model->{$model->getKeyName()})->count();
    }
}
```

.

```
if ($user->hasPivot('tags', $tag)){
    // do some things...
}
```

Comment: Didn't solve my issue but helped me getting on the right path, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This has time but maybe I can help someone

```
if($client->products()->find($product->id)){
 exists!!
}
```

It should be noted that you must have the product and customer model, I hope it helps,

Comment: Yes, it helps for me. It returns a related model or null if the model is not found by identificator.

Comment: Instead of using the `->find()` method, How to detect if there's at least one record? In my case, I want to get all the clients that have at least one product, since I previously don't know the `$product->id`