# Laravel: find if a pivot table record exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have two models which are joined by a pivot table, `User` and `Task`.

I have a `user_id` and a `task_id`.

What is the neatest way to check whether a record exists for this combination of user and task?

Comment: I hope this will be solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555697/check-if-belongstomany-relation-exists-laravel

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have a couple options depending on your situation.

If you already have a `User` instance and you want to see if it has a task with a certain id, you can do:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$hasTask = $user->tasks()->where('id', $taskId)->exists();
```

You can reverse this if you have the `Task` instance and want to check for a user:

```
$task = Task::find(1);
$hasUser = $task->users()->where('id', $userId)->exists();
```

If you just have the ids, without an instance of each, you could do the following:

```
$hasPivot = User::where('id', $userId)->whereHas('tasks', function ($q) use ($taskId) {
        $q->where('id', $taskId);
    })
    ->exists();
```

Comment: @patricus, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519339/how-can-i-update-pivot-table-on-laravel

Comment: In my case, what works, considering your example table and column names is: `$user->userTasks()->where('task_id', $taskId)->exists();` but it depends on definition inside of the model files, of course.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try this, this is working in Laravel 5.7

```
$user = User::find(1);
$hasTask = $user->tasks->contains($taskId);
```

But the better way will be

```
$hasTask = $user->tasks()->where('tasks.id', $taskId)->exists();
```

Comment: Avoid doing is - this retrieves all the tasks for a certain user, puts them in memory and then checks if the $taskId is in there.

Comment: @Eduardo  yes people should prefer eager loading or relationship query instead of collection for checking this.

Comment: @Eduardo I have updated my answer, I think this will be better this way.

Answer (score 6):

may be you search this?

```
$users = User::has('task')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest to read for me is:

```
$user->tasks()->exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
if($user->tasks->find($task_id){
  //user has task
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the code below:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$hasTask = $user->tasks()->where('task_id', $taskId)->exists();
```