# Laravel ManyToMany retrieving data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm new to Laravel and breaking my head trying to work with relationships.

I have 2 tables:
members
groups

And a pivot table: member_group

A member can belong to many groups, a group can have many members.

When I edit a member, I create checkboxes for the groups.

I need to mark the ones that the member already has as 'checked'

My edit method:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $cities = City::orderBy('city_name')->pluck('city_name', 'city_id');
    $member = Member::findOrFail($id);
    $groups = Group::all();

    return view('members.edit', compact('member', 'cities', 'groups'));
}
```

In my edit.blade:

```
@foreach($groups as $group)
 <?php $exists = $member->groups()->where('groups.group_id', $member->group_id); ?>
 @if($exists)
 <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="{{ $group->group_id }}" checked> {{ $group->group_name }}
 @else
 <input type="checkbox" name="groups[]" value="{{ $group->group_id }}"> {{ $group->group_name }}
 @endif
```

....

All the checkboxes are checked, although the member does not belong to all the groups.

Looking at this post: [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555697/check-if-belongstomany-relation-exists-laravel) I tried almost everything they offer there, only got errors. The only one that works is this one:
$exists = $member->groups->contains($group->group_id);

Don't know about wastefulness or not, it's the only one that works.

Comment: Can you post some code or elaborate where exactly you are stucked at ?

Comment: My edit method:
` public function edit($id)
    {
        $cities = City::orderBy('city_name')->pluck('city_name', 'city_id');
        $member = Member::findOrFail($id);
        $groups = Group::all();
                       
        return view('members.edit', compact('member', 'cities', 'groups'));
    }`
My blade:

Comment: please update your question with details. :)

Comment: :) Updated my question. I forgot how hard it is to comment here with details

Comment: what you are trying to do `$exists = $member->groups()->where('groups.group_id', $member->group_id);` here ?

Comment: I found it in one of the many posts I found regarding this question.
I am trying to set checkboxes for all the groups and have the ones that the member belongs to 'checked'. The point is, I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your blade `$exists = $member->groups()->where('groups.group_id', $member->group_id);` you should use `group.group_id` instead of `groups.group_id` and also use `first()` method.

```
$exists = $member->groups()->where('group.group_id', $member->group_id)->first();
```

### Update:

Can you try this ?

```
$member = Member::findOrFail($id)->with(['groups'=>function($query){
    $query->selectRaw('groups.group_id');
}])->first();
```

And in blade:

```
$exists = $member->groups()->whereIn('groups.group_id', $member->groups)->first();
```

Comment: Getting this: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group.group_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `groups`.*, `group_member`.`member_id` as `pivot_member_id`, `group_member`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id` from `groups` inner join `group_member` on `groups`.`group_id` = `group_member`.`group_id` where `group_member`.`member_id` = 1 and `group`.`group_id` is null order by `group_name` asc limit 1) (View: C:\wamp\www\ccf.local\resources\views\members\edit.blade.php)

Comment: Changed it to groups.group_id, now none of the checkboxes are checked but the member belongs to 2 groups

Comment: @SigalZahavi I'm so sorry I confused `groups` with `variable` instead of table name

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no group_id in the members table, there is a pivot table for that. Or am I wrong? Don't be sorry, I appreciate you're trying to help!

Comment: could you please try the update? not sure if this will execute without error, didn't check it. Though, you will get the idea.

Comment: I updated my question with the only solution I found