# Flag a relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have posts and users models. A user can bookmark a post. I store these bookmarks in a pivot table that has `user_id` and `post_id` on it.

I need to get all posts out and flag if the current logged in user has bookmarked the post (to add a class to an icon).

```
return Post::with('bookmarks')->get();
```

The above gets all bookmarks for a post, how can I flag it so that I know if the logged in user has bookmarked a particular post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate trough posts collection and add new attribute

```
return Post::with('bookmarks')->get()->each(function (Post $post) {
    $post->bookmarked = $post->bookmarks->filter(function (Bookmark $bookmark) {
        return $bookmark->user_id === Auth::id();
    })->count() > 0;
})
```

Then you can check `$post->bookmarked` - it's boolean value.

You should check before `->each(...)` method that user is logged - if not you shouldn't iterate posts collection.

Comment: Thanks i'll check this out.

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong with this solution? Simple and workable

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-contains) method to check if user bookmarked given post:

```
auth()->user()->posts->contains($postId)
```

[Another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555697/check-if-belongstomany-relation-exists-laravel/48083887#48083887) to do that is to use `whereHas()`:

```
$isBookmarked = Post::where('id', $postId)
    ->whereHas('users', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    })->count();
```

**Update**

You've said you want to preload all posts (for all users). I've just tested this solution and it will not make any additional queries.

First, load all the data as you wanted:

```
$posts = Post::with('users')->get();
```

Then you can check if relationship between any post and any user exists without executing any additional queries:

```
$isBookmarked = $posts->firstWhere('id', $postId)->users->contains($userId);
```

Comment: But wont I then be transferring the entire collection of bookmarks from the database? Doesnt seem right.

Comment: @panthro yep, but only bookmarks for a current user. It's not a perfect solution. You could try `whereHas()` solution. I've updated my answer. You could also use query builder for that if it's an option. Or you could create a model for a pivot table and use it to find a match.

Comment: Thanks, anyway to return a flag of true or false in the whereHas query?

Comment: @panthro my code will return `true` or `false` because of `isNotEmpty()`.

Comment: Yes but I still need the lists of posts.

Comment: Also this will not work for posts with no bookmarks.

Comment: @panthro if you want to load posts, use `contains()` as I've shown. For example `$posts = auth()->user()->posts; $posts->contains($postId)`. Also, both methods will work for posts with no bookmarks. It will just return `false` if relationship doesn't exist.

Comment: I dont want to use contains - its inefficient. And the second method will not return all posts, just true or false, my question is how to return a flag alongside posts.

Comment: @panthro you've said you want to load posts anyway. In this case, there will be no overhead at all.

Comment: There will be overhead loading all of the bookmarks and sending them from the server.

Comment: Dude, bookmarks is a pivot table. You're not loading bookmarks. You're loading posts. When you do `$posts = auth()->user()->posts` it will load all products for that user. You need to do this, right? Then you'll just do this `$posts->contains($postId)`. It will not execute any additional query.

Comment: But I dont want to load all posts for a user, I want to loads all posts. There is a difference.

Comment: My original question does show that in the example. And again - i do not want to use contains it is inefficient.

Comment: @panthro `contains()` will not create any additional queries if you'll use it as I've shown in a previous comment.

Comment: But it does mean I have to get the entire lot of bookmarks from the database.

Comment: @panthro I've tested the code and added it to the answer. Please check.

Comment: Your update will only get the first post. I need a list of posts, each with a flag if the user has bookmarked the post. Its clear in my question.

Comment: @panthro no it's not. You load all the data into memory. You will have a nested collection of posts with related users. Then you just work with this data. I've tested it and it works perfectly. Just take your time and test it.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin your solution is computationally complex. On every post you iterate through whole collection - you got O(n^2). It's really bad idea. You have Laravel best practices repository, please consider that and do not publish bad practices.

Comment: @ventaqui the original OP's question wasn't about checking bookmark for every `Post`. In this case, OP could just iterate over a collection and check each `Post` but he never said he needs that. Also, I'm pretty sure your solution will have near the same speed as mine if I would iterate over a collection. `filter()` in a loop can't be much faster (or faster at all) than iterating with using `contains()`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin agree, I also has O(n^2) complexity. - but I do it once.